# Like-condition in CouchDB

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I want to perform a LIKE-condition (SQL syntax) in CouchDB. How can this be done? The LIKE-condition will be used to perform auto complete in the browser.

I want to write "co" in the input field and get the results Coffee, Couch, CouchDB ect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is very easy to search for letters at the beginning of a string. You just need a view that emits the string you want to search for as the key. Assuming the user input is stored in a variable `q`, you then call that view with the parameters `startkey=q` and `endkey=q+"\ufff0"`.

The trick here is to append the highest possible Unicode character to the search string. In the sort order, this string comes after anything else starting with `q`. (This is much easier to implement than the solution suggested by @titanoboa, where you need to "increment" the last letter of the user input.)

If you also want to be able to find words in the middle of a string (e.g. "The Colbert Report" when typing "co"), you could use a view like this:

```
function(doc) {
  if (doc.title) {
    var words = {};
    doc.title.replace(/\w+/g, function(word) {
      words[word.toLowerCase()] = true;
    });
    for (w in words) {
      emit(w, doc);
    }
  }
}
```

Of course this is only advisable for short strings. For searching in longer texts you should look into a full-text search add-on like [couchdb-lucene](http://github.com/rnewson/couchdb-lucene).

Comment: Why is the highest possible Unicode character `fff0` and not `ffff`?

Comment: @Jez That's a good question, I have no idea why I wrote `\ufff0` back then. I suppose the correct code point would `\u{10FFFF}`, but I haven't tested this. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description)

Answer (score 0):

That won't work with CouchDB alone. The best thing to try is the Lucene search engine which works well with CouchDB. Lucene is designed for full-text searching which is basically what you are looking for. [Here](http://wiki.fluidproject.org/display/fluid/Setting+Up+CouchDB+and+Lucene) are some instructions on the combination.

Answer (score 0):

To implement your example, you could create a view which has your field as a key and the same field, the whole document or whatever you want as a value. If you query the view with the parameters `startkey="co", endkey="cp", inclusive_end=false`, you'll get all entries with a key that starts with "co".

Of course, this is less powerful than 'LIKE'.