# CouchDB select all where field contains value

Tags: sql, couchdb

Is it possible to select all documents where a field contains a value.

i.e is the following sql possible?

```
Select * FROM table WHERE field LIKE %substring%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no exact equivalent to the SQL-keyword `LIKE` in CouchDB. Depending on your use case, you may achieve something similar by building an appropriate index.

Take a look at this question: [Like-condition in CouchDB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3716857)